# Migrating Adobe Flex web application to Adobe AIR package application - ExternalInterface.call failing

Tags: air, adobe, flex4, flex3, flex4.5

As support for Adobe Flex is ending in 2020, we are migrating Adobe Flex web application into Adobe AIR standalone application
as steps below
Creating certificate
`./adt -certificate -cn SelfSigned 1024-RSA sampleCert.p12 samplePassword`
Creating AIR application

`./adt -package -keystore ./sampleCert.p12 -storetype pkcs12 -target bundle AIRApp.app App-descriptor.xml App.swf`

In many places we make call to ExternalInterface like below

`ExternalInterface.call("window.location.search.toString");`
and exception is thrown

````
    at Error$/throwError()
    at flash.external::ExternalInterface$/call()```
 

Is there a way to enable ExternalInterface in Adobe AIR?
````

Answer (score 0):

ExternalInterface is for calling Javascript functions in the enclosing HTML page of the Flex app. ExternalInterface does not exist in AIR because it has no enclosing HTML page/Javascript.

You will have to review each ExternalInterface call in the Flex app, and write an equivalent in AIR. The Adobe AIR API may be useful